# Parsing PHP/JSON data in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

I'm trying to communicate AJAX, JSON to PHP and then PHP returns some data and I'm trying to parse it with Javascrpt.

From the php, server I return,

```
    echo json_encode($data); 

    // it outputs ["123","something","and more something"]
```

and then in client-side,

```
success : function(data){

    //I want the data as following

    // data[0] = 123
    // data[1] = something
    // data[3] = and more something
}
```

But, it gives as;

```
        data[0] = [ 
        data[1] = " 
        data[2] = 1
```

It is reading each character but I want strings from the array, not individual characters. What is happening here? Thanks in advance, I am new to Javascript and JSON, AJAX.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`JSON.parse(data)` should do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

Set the `dataType` property of the ajax call to `json`. Then jQuery will automatically convert your response to object representation.

```
$.ajax({
    url : ...,
    data : ...,
    dataType : "json",
    success : function(json) {
        console.log(json);
    }
});
```

Another option is to set headers in PHP so that JQuery understand that you send a JSON object.

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 3):

**Check this one...  Should Work**

success : function(data){

```
var result = data;

result=result.replace("[","");

result=result.replace("]","");

var arr = new Array();

arr=result.split(",")

alert(arr[0]); //123

alert(arr[1]); //something

alert(arr[2]); //......
}
```

Comment: if nothing works, i was thinking to do this, but as the last option.. thanks though. :)

Answer (score 1):

You did not shown function in which you parse data. But you shoud use

```
JSON.parse
```

and if broser does not support JSON then use json polyfill from https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

```
dataArray = JSON.parse(dataFomXHR);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you want but why don't you want php to return it in this format:

```
{'item1':'123','item2':'something','item3':'and more something'}
```

Well to achieve this, you'll need to make sure the array you `json_encode()` is associative.
It should be in the form below

```
array("item1"=>123,"item2"=>"something","item3"=>"more something");
```

You could even go ahead to do a `stripslashes()` in the event that some of the values in the array could be URLs

You could then do a `JSON.parse()` on the JSON string and access the values

Hop this helps!